# update-alternatives very slow in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, aptitude

Every time I try to install a package which require the "update-alternatives" for the JRE, apt-get doesn't respond anymore:

```
Setting up sun-java6-bin (6.20dlj-1ubuntu3) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/ControlPanel to provide /usr/bin/ControlPanel (ControlPanel) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java_vm to provide /usr/bin/java_vm (java_vm) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/javaws to provide /usr/bin/javaws (javaws) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/jcontrol to provide /usr/bin/jcontrol (jcontrol) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/keytool to provide /usr/bin/keytool (keytool) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/pack200 to provide /usr/bin/pack200 (pack200) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/policytool to provide /usr/bin/policytool (policytool) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/rmid to provide /usr/bin/rmid (rmid) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/rmiregistry to provide /usr/bin/rmiregistry (rmiregistry) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/unpack200 to provide /usr/bin/unpack200 (unpack200) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/orbd to provide /usr/bin/orbd (orbd) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/servertool to provide /usr/bin/servertool (servertool) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/tnameserv to provide /usr/bin/tnameserv (tnameserv) in auto mode.
```

And then nothing else. I've tried to leave it for half an hour, but nothing happens.

Did anyone encounter this issue before?

Comment: I've been running into this same issue, did you find out what was going wrong?

Comment: I was running this on an EC2 small image. Using a bigger image helped.